# Text In textView is not showing but the java code work. If i add autoLink="web" tag to textview , the text shows but java code doesn't

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

Text In textView is not showing but the java code work. If i add autoLink="web" tag to textview , the text shows but java code doesn't work. When the textview is pressed , user should be redirected to contact email.

This is the text view xml.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

If i add any autoLink tag , the text in textview shows but the user is not redirected to email.
If i remove the tag , user is redirected to email but the textview text is not showing.

This is the java code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.MailTo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactUs extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);

        TextView mail =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewContact);
        mail.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:confidential@gmail.com\">Contact Us</a>"));
        mail.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below code to your activity as the method you are using is deprecated

For kotlin, use below code snippet

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        mail.text = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:confidential@gmail.com\">Contact Us</a>",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    } else {
        mail.text = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:confidential@gmail.com\">Contact Us</a>")
    }
```

For Java, Use below lines

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        mail.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:confidential@gmail.com\">Contact Us</a>",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        mail.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:confidential@gmail.com\">Contact Us</a>"));
}
```

Also there is no need of autolink property in the TextView tag. You can skip this line in xml and you will be able to see the Contact Us text and clicking on link will navigate you to gmail.
[image]

Comment: `error: cannot find symbol
            mail.text = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:confidential@gmail.com\">Contact Us</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
                ^
  symbol:   variable text`

Comment: Just use setText method here as you are using in your code, The code i have shared is in Kotlin, You are using java.

Comment: the textview is working but still no text is showing

Comment: You mean you are not able to see the text after running the app on device or emulator?

Comment: Which sdk version are you using in gradle? I have checked same at my end, It is working fine.

Comment: minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: What are the other xml attributes? I have same gradle configuration as yours, but no issue is there.

Comment: you can see in the question all the atributes

Comment: I have added an image to answer ,xml code is as below

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

Comment: This Widget is defined in Constraint layout with height and width match parent.

Comment: Its exactly the same. i dont know why is not showing the text. thank you for your help